# Concatenate difference to the data found in CSV with javascript

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I can search  for the filename within the CSV, and check if it is already there:

```
//Open created .csv and check if file is already there

folderName = "~/Desktop/"
docRef = activeDocument;
var now = new Date();
var logfile_name = now.getFullYear() + "-"+ now.getMonth() + "-" + now.getDate() + '.csv'

var fileOut = new File(folderName+logfile_name);

fileOut.open("r");
var str ="";
while(!fileOut.eof)
str += fileOut.readln();

fileOut.close();

//input what to search for
var n = str.match(docRef.name);
```

I can always add a new line and still preserve the header with:

```
folderName = "~/Desktop/"

//Create File with todays date
var now = new Date();
var logfile_name = now.getFullYear() + "-"+ now.getMonth() + "-" + now.getDate() + '.csv'
var fileOut = new File(folderName+logfile_name);

if (!fileOut.exists) {
fileOut.open("w");
fileOut.writeln("Filename, Department, Steps, Tools, Liquify, Pen Tool, Clone Stamp, Patch Tool, Spot Healing Brush, Free Transform, Dust and Scratches, Color Correction, Replace Color");
fileOut.writeln(docRef.name, ",", departmentNumber, ",", MyHistoryStates, ",", HowManyTools, ",", liquifyUsed, ",", pentoolUsed, ",", clonestampUsed, ",", patchtoolUsed, ",", spothealingbrushUsed, ",", freetransformUsed, ",", dustandscratchesUsed, ",", colorcorrectionUsed, ",", replacecolorUsed);
} else {
fileOut.open("a");
fileOut.writeln(docRef.name, ",", departmentNumber, ",", MyHistoryStates, ",", HowManyTools, ",", liquifyUsed, ",", pentoolUsed, ",", clonestampUsed, ",", patchtoolUsed, ",", spothealingbrushUsed, ",", freetransformUsed, ",", dustandscratchesUsed, ",", colorcorrectionUsed, ",", replacecolorUsed);

}

fileOut.close();
```

Currently, after 3 runs it outputs as below:
[image]

But what I am trying to do right now is, so that on the next time I run the script, It would check:

- if filename is already in CSV, then `concatenate` `MyHistoryStates` ('Steps' in the CSV).
- if any of the 9 Boolean values have changed, then replace it with the new value.
- all without creating new lines/cells, simply by updating what's already there

So it would look somehting like this:
[image]

Not sure if that makes sense :(

Comment: Why not using a well-known csv lib like [csv-parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parse)? Then you can easily parse/generate csv based on the object model and change it easily.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this: creat an object of objects with all the data and filename as a property. If new filename is already in this object, update the steps and the things you need, if it's not in the object, add it as a new item. Then convert objects back to strings and write csv file.

```
//fileOut is defined already
fileOut.open("r");
var myObj = {};
while (!fileOut.eof)
{
    var csvLine = fileOut.readln().split(','); //create an array from csv string
    myObj[csvLine[0]] = createObject(csvLine); //create an object {'S208032.tif':{department: 32, steps: 5, tools: false, etc}}
};

//newCsvFile is defined already and is an array, similar to fileOut.readln().split(',')
myNewData[newCsvFile[0]] = createObject(newCsvFile)

for (var fileName in myObj)
{
    // if filename from newCsvFile is already in the csv
    if (fileName == newCsvFile[0])
    {
        //update steps
        myObj[fileName].steps += myNewData[fileName].steps;

        // change other properties as you want
        myObj[fileName].liquify = myNewData[fileName].liquify
        // etc...
    }
    // if filename from newCsvFile isn't in the csv
    else
    {
        //create a new entry in myObj with data from the new string
        myObj[newCsvFile[0]] = myNewData[newCsvFile[0]];
    }
};

//transform objects to strings
//write csv file

function createObject(data)
{
    return {
        department: data[1],
        steps: data[2],
        tools: data[3],
        liquify: data[4],
        //etc...
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! The first part works! It converts an array from csv string and creates an object. But then the 2nd half, when it has to go and compare, it throws an `Error 25: Expected: ;.` at `//newCsvFile is defined already and is an array, similar to fileOut.readln().split(',') var myNewData[newCsvFile[0]] = createObject(newCsvFile);` You gave me a good headstart though!

Comment: Sorry, my bad, `var` isn't needed there, forgot to remove it. I've updated my answer

Comment: It says `newCsvFile is undefined` :P When I try to define it - it runs, but then it doesn't update the existing data in CSV. How do you define `newCsvFile`? can't figure out what is it in your script. Temp for the new Csv just for the sake of comparison?

Comment: `newCsvFile` is your new data that you want to update the existing data with